# How to get the circumscribed area of all DOM elements?

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of elements on the page. I need to draw a circumscribed rectangle that contains all DOM elements.

For that I iterate DOM elements and get rectangle:

```
Array.from(firstChild.children).forEach((child: Element) => {
      const rect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
});
```

Which props I need from `rect` to do that?
Logically I need to get minimal x,y of `left-top` corner and max `bottom-right` corner. But how?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're looking to achieve ? That'd surely help us understand your issue.

Comment: why don't you get the bounding rectangle for the `<body>` which contains all your elements of the view?

Comment: @Manish: It might not contain all elements (absolute positioning, etc.), and it might be too big.

Comment: `(child: Element)` is not valid JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply a border you need to set 4 values: `top`, `left`, `width` and `height`.

Getting `top` and `left` can be easily done by finding the topmost and leftmost elements. To get the other values you should do some calculation:

`width = rightmost - leftmost` and `height = bottommost - topmost`

To get `rightmost` and `bottommost` you have to loop through all elements and get their rightmost/bottommost points with the same formula, but you need to rearrange them. Here you should keep the biggest values.

```js
//select all elements that should be inside the rectangle
const myElements = document.querySelectorAll("div#container *")

//set initial values, I made sure they are always smaller/bigger than they will be
let Top=Infinity, Left=Infinity, Bottom=-Infinity, Right=-Infinity;
for(const i of myElements){
  //loop through the elements
  const data = i.getBoundingClientRect()
  Top = Math.min(Top, data.top)
  Bottom = Math.max(Bottom, data.top+data.height)
  Left = Math.min(Left, data.left)
  Right = Math.max(Right, data.left+data.width)
}

console.log(Top, Left, Bottom, Right) // print out the coordinates
//set the border
//I subtract 1px bacuse of the border width
const myBorder = document.querySelector("#border")
myBorder.style.top=Top-1+"px"
myBorder.style.left=Left-1+"px"
myBorder.style.width=Right-Left+"px"
myBorder.style.height=Bottom-Top+"px"
```

```css
#t1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
}
#t2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #111;
}
#t3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -40px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #800;
}
#t4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #444;
}
#border{
  border: solid red 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="t1"></div>
  <div id="t2">
    <div id="t3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="t4"></div>
</div>
<div id="border"></div>
```

Comment: Could you comment how does it work?

Comment: If you still need it, I've added some explanation